# Animating images using JSON and XML

Tags: android, json, xml, animation, video-processing

I surf lot about how to perform animations usign .json and .xml files which contains some values and factor which can create animation with some images.

As i am new to this i am not getting how can i achive this.
Here are some requied items like it's .json and .xml files with the images.

Here is `.json` File

```
{
  "effectList": [
    {
      "duration": 6000,
      "end_time": 99999999,
      "path": "01/", // folder name of Device
      "start_time": 0,
      "type": 1
    },
    {
      "duration": 3000,
      "end_time": 0,
      "path": "02/",
      "start_time": 0,
      "type": 2
    },
    {
      "duration": 3000,
      "end_time": 0,
      "path": "03/",
      "start_time": 0,
      "type": 2
    }
  ],
  "backgroundColor": 3,
  "moveType": 2,
  "musicConfig": "{\"zh\":\"abc\",\"path\":\"music/Seductive Blues.m4a\",\"en\":\"Seductive Blues\"}",
  "clip_duration": [
    0,
    0
  ],
  "isTransRand": 0
}
```

[Click here to see [Xml File][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgc5f.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgc5f.png)

Here is the output that i want to create
[Output Like[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHfFG.gif)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHfFG.gif)

Here are 2 images that is using in json and xml.

Named as 1.jpg [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8n0f.jpg) and 2.jpg [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Skn7X.jpg)

Any small help is considrable and appriceated in advance. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To animate images using `xml`, you can use `Frame Animations`(aka `Drawable Animations`). In this, you define the Frame animation in XML, place it in the `res/drawable/` folder, and set it as the background to a View object. Then, call `start()` to run the animation.

An `AnimationDrawable` defined in XML consists of a single `<animation-list>` element and a series of nested `<item>` tags. Each item defines a frame of the animation. An example of this is:

`animation.xml` file in `res/drawable/` folder:

```
 <!-- Animation frames are 1.png through 6.png files inside the res/drawable/ folder -->
 <animation-list android:id="@+id/selected" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/1" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/2" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/3" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/4" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/5" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/6" android:duration="50" />
 </animation-list>
```

To load and play this animation.

```
// Load the ImageView that will host the animation and
 // set its background to our AnimationDrawable XML resource.
 ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.spinning_wheel_image);
 img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spin_animation); 

// Get the background, which has been compiled to an AnimationDrawable object.
 AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();

 // Start the animation (looped playback by default).
 frameAnimation.start();
```

Reference Documentation:

[AnimationDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html)

[Drawable Animation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html)

As far as `json` is concerned, I think only [Lottie Animations](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android) use json to animate images.

Comment: Thank you @Abhi, i have already see this lottie Animation . But i can not understand how to use this with my application. can you please let me help in this?

Comment: The lottie animation is used to animate images by supplying json data to After Effects. Lottie is a plugin used in Adobe After Effects. There are several tutorials on google on how to integrate Lottie with Android. See [this](https://medium.com/@daniel.nesfeder/android-animations-with-lottie-d4aa5a5f237), [this](https://medium.com/@christopherdeane/native-app-animations-in-android-studio-using-lottie-from-airbnb-bbc039c87e63). You can google it yourself.

Comment: Was your question answered?